# How to apply regex to string arrays in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the following class mapped as a Neo4j node:

```
public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Synonyms { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that database searches should match against the **Name** property, or any item in the **Synonyms** array:

The following search performs **case-sensitive** matches (clipped for brevity):

```
START (...) WHERE item.Name = "searchTerm") OR ("searchTerm" IN item.Synonyms!) RETURN item;
```

I'm attempting to perform **case-insensitive** matches, but only got as far as this:

```
START (...) WHERE item.Name =~ '(?i)searchTerm') OR ("searchTerm" IN item.Synonyms!) RETURN item;
```

Is it possible to perform case-insensitive matches against the **Synonyms** string array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resorted to this, which seems to do the trick:

```
WHERE item.Name =~ '(?i)searchTerm') OR (ANY(s IN item.Synonyms! WHERE s =~ '(?i)searchTerm')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `str()` function:

```
WHERE str(item.Synonyms) =~ '(?).*whatever.*'
```